# How can I change the numbering style for subhypotheses?

Tags: numbering, theorems, ntheorem

I want to change the numbering of Subhypothesis so that the subhypothesis which is after Hypothesis 1, is numbered 'Subhypothesis 1.1.

How can I do that?

My code for now is as following.

```
\usepackage{ntheorem} 
\theoremseparator{:} 
\newtheorem[number within=section]{hyp}{Hypothesis} 
\newtheorem {subhyp}{Subhypothesis}
```

Thank you

Comment: `number within=hyp` for the environment `subhyp` should work

Comment: Are subhypotheses always associated with a (main) hypothesis, or can there be "standalone" subhypotheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following setup is (probably) close to what you want:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}[section]
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Subhypothesis}[hyp]
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example); compile with pdflatex, lualatex, or xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}[section]
\newtheorem{subhyp}{Subhypothesis}[hyp]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{hyp}    aaa \label{hyp:aaa} \end{hyp}    % 3.1
\begin{subhyp} bbb \label{hyp:bbb} \end{subhyp} % 3.1.1
\begin{hyp}    uuu \label{hyp:uuu} \end{hyp}    % 3.2

\refstepcounter{section}
\begin{hyp}    ccc \label{hyp:ccc} \end{hyp}    % 4.1
\begin{subhyp} ddd \label{hyp:ddd} \end{subhyp} % 4.1.1
\begin{subhyp} eee \label{hyp:eee} \end{subhyp} % 4.1.2:

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Could you also tell me how I can change the writing style of these new theorems, because the italics in which it is written right now, is sort of confusing in regards to quotes.

Comment: @thebilly - Please clarify your formatting objectives. E.g., do you want to use upright, rather than italic, letters for both `hyp` and `subhyp` environmetns, or just for the subhypothesis enviroments?

Comment: For both hyp and subhyp environments, I want to change the font used (by default) I could use \textsf in each environment to change the font, but I'd prefer if it would be like that by default.

Comment: @thebilly - The `ntheorem` package comes with an excellent, crisp user guide. Highly recommended reading, for anyone who's contemplating changing the defaults. Really! (Incidentally, you've already made one change to the default, by executing `\theoremseparator{:}`.) Perusing page 5 of the package's user guide, you'd find that executing `\theorembodyfont{\sffamily}` would achieve what you're seeking to do. Run this command before executing any `\newtheorem` instructions.